# How do I refer to my form elements' values in a query? C# MSSQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

I'm trying to insert data from my textbox value to the database.
This code works perfectly fine

```
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO GuestTable (CustomerName, Address) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "')", con);
```

But I only need to insert that data to a specified ID. So I figured I need to add this:

```
  WHERE CustomerID = '" +Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text)+"'
```

But that line gives an error only after I ran the program saying, "Error near 'WHERE' keyword.."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you do not do it like that. You should never use string concatenation within an SQL query. In C#, you should be using Parameterized Queries. Then, you can use the methods C# provides to insert your variables into the query.

Here is an example taken from [Using Parameterized Query to Avoid SQL Injection](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/why-should-always-use-the-parameterized-query-to-avoid-sql-i/)

```
string sql = "select count(UserID) from user_login where UserID=@UserID and pwd=@pwd";  
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);  
SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[2];  
param[0] = new SqlParameter("@UserID", txtUSerID.Text);  
param[1] = new SqlParameter("@pwd", txtPwd.Text);  
cmd.Parameters.Add(param[0]);  
cmd.Parameters.Add(param[1]);
```